# With Django REST framework, how do I parse a RESTful string parameter?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, parameters, restful-url

I'm using Python 3.9 with

```
Django==3.1.4
djangorestframework==3.12.2
```

I want to pass a restful param ("author" string) to my GET method.  In my urls.py file I have

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('user/<str:author>', views.UserView.as_view()),
```

And then in my UserView class (defined in my views.py file), I have

```
class UserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        ...
        author = self.kwargs.get('author', None)
```

but when i execute

```
GET http://localhost:8000/user/myauthor
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'author'
```

What else do I need to do to properly access my RESTful param in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the path params added in the url pattern, you must add the `**kwargs` as an extra parameter to the `get()` method. Your view should look like this:

```
class UserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
       ...
       author = kwargs.get('author', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

`get()` method should accept url parameters too, you can use `*args` and `**kwargs` syntax to make sure it works no matter how you name your parameter:

```
class UserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        author = self.kwargs.get('author', None)
```

Comment: You should use `kwargs` instead of `self.kwargs`